# Calling Base REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call the Base API which requires the Accept and Authorization headers. I have the following code in a console app but always get a 400 error.  I have intercepted the call in fiddler and the headers are not present. The call works if I manually create it in fiddler. Am I missing something form the request?

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.getbase.com/");

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("v2/users/self");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the documentation https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/first_call

Comment: Show the raw request data from fiddler

Comment: {"errors":[{"error":{"code":"invalid_header","message":"invalid request header","details":"The header 'User-Agent' is malformed, missing, or has an invalid value."},"meta":{"type":"error","links":{"more_info":"https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/errors"}}}],"meta":{"type":"errors","http_status":"400 Bad Request","logref":"ae7ha-o2kd1-3irpe-q235g","links":{"more_info":"https://developers.getbase.com/docs/rest/articles/errors"}}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should add `User-Agent` header to the request as the error message is telling you to do this.

> error":{"code":"invalid_header","message":"invalid request
>   header","details":"The header 'User-Agent' is malformed, missing, or
>   has an invalid value."

Answer (score 1):

Below example works when using curl php, notice the line with 'User-Agent'
Don't forget the $ACESS_TOKEN.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.getbase.com/v2/leads');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'User-agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], // USER-AGENT 
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' .$ACCESS_TOKEN
    )
);
```